# Jquery custom gallery with keyboard navigation bahviour

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to create an image gallery with keyboard navigation.
Most of it works correctly except for some small stuff. The gallery should have 3 states. Top, center and bottom state. See included image:

[image]

In some cases when you 'scroll' up and down through the gallery too fast it gets 'scrambled'.

Wrong state:

[image]

My guess is that the keyboard event is registered before the animation finishes.
Any help with this problem is much appreciated.

Fiddle: 
[http://jsfiddle.net/sb3nqtnr/1/](http://jsfiddle.net/sb3nqtnr/)

```
var y_pos = 1,
x_pos = 1,
item_position = 1;
var gallery_li = $('.gallery > ul > li');
var gallery_ul = $('.gallery');
var total_items = gallery_li.length;
var num_cols = 3;
var num_rows = Math.ceil(total_items / num_cols);
var li_height = gallery_li.height();
var li_margin = gallery_li.css("margin-top").replace("px", "");
var move_margin = 0;
var li_offset = li_height + (1.5 * li_margin);

$('.gallery > ul > li').each(function(i) {
    $(this).attr('id', 'property_' + (i + 1));
    $(this).text('TEST ' + (i + 1))
});

selectItem(1);

function selectItem(pos) {
    var item_position = pos;
    gallery_li.removeClass('active');
    var item = $('.gallery > ul > li:nth-child(' + item_position + ')');
    item.addClass('active');
}

//calculate number of li per row
function calculateLIsInRow() {
    var lisInRow = 0;
    $('.gallery > ul > li').each(function() {
        if ($(this).prev().length > 0) {
            if ($(this).position().top != $(this).prev().position().top) return false;
            lisInRow++;
        } else {
            lisInRow++;
        }
    });
    return lisInRow;
}

$("html").on("keydown", function(event) {
    keyCode = event.which;

    var current_position = y_pos + x_pos;
    var gallery_ul = $('.gallery > ul');
    var gallery_ul_mt = gallery_ul.css("margin-top").replace("px", "");


    if (keyCode == 37) {
        //move left
        if (x_pos > 1) {
            x_pos--;
        }

    } else if (keyCode == 39) {
        //move right
        if (x_pos < num_cols && item_position < total_items) {
            x_pos++;
        }

    } else if (keyCode == 38) {
        //move up
        if (y_pos > 1) {
            y_pos--;

            if (y_pos > 1) {
                move_margin += li_offset;
                gallery_ul.stop(true, true).finish().animate({
                    marginTop: move_margin
                }, 500);
            }

        }

    } else if (keyCode == 40) {
        //move down
        if (y_pos < num_rows && (item_position + num_cols <= total_items)) {
            y_pos++;

            if (y_pos > 2 && (y_pos + 1 <= num_rows)) {
                move_margin -= li_offset;
                gallery_ul.stop(true, true).finish().animate({
                    marginTop: move_margin
                }, 500);
            }
        }
    }


    item_position = (x_pos * y_pos) + ((num_cols - x_pos) * (y_pos - 1));
    selectItem(item_position);
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed this problem myself.

The problem was adding and subtracting the top offset.

```
move_margin -= li_offset;
```

Had to change that to calculating the position based on the selected row/y-position:

```
move_margin = -(y_pos-2) * li_offset;
```

**[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sb3nqtnr/3/)**